# Changing the body text size in the MNRAS \documentclass

Tags: spacing, formatting, fontsize, overleaf

I'm an Astronomy undergraduate currently working on my senior project. I've used LaTeX [specifically in Overleaf] a few times previously, but I'm still very much a novice working with it.

The problem I'm currently facing is a specific formatting requirement in the report for said project- quote,

"*You must use a minimum font size of 11pt for the main text, and page margins of at least 2cm.*"

I'm currently using the MNRAS Document class [as I am somewhat familiar with it, having used it previously]

The template, with the relevant .cls file, can be found here (https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/monthly-notices-of-the-royal-astronomical-society-mnras-latex-template-and-guide-for-authors/kqnjzrwjwjth)

What I'm trying to do is change the font size corresponding to the main body of the text to increase its size and spacing. I *assume* it has something to do with the segment titled "font sizes" but, to be frank, the commands in the .cls file are something I have no experience with.

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.